# Is there a way to add info to a link and when clicked will auto fill the forums on the page?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a link that I have to click on each day and fill out some information (username, pass, code). I was wondering if there was anyway I could edit the link and just click on it each day and it will auto fill my account on the page. 
the code for the html elements on the page are:

```
<input type="text" name="u" tabindex="1" size="15" id=usrname" value>
<input type="password" name="pw" tabindex="3" size="15" autocomplete="off" id="password">
```

Any ideas would be great!

If that doesn't make since maybe this will
www.example.com/?usrname=alex,password=12345

Maybe I am just searching the wrong things, please advise send me links anything. Thanks guys!

Comment: username and password in url ... are you kidding ?

Comment: it's `www.example.com/?usrname=alex&password=12345`

Answer (score 0):

If that '`html`' is controlled by you, you can remove `'autocomplete="off"'` - this will show the `username`(why you start typing). If not, I am afraid that you can't do anything for this because neither the server nor the client side is controlled by you.

*Just to mention it* - you should **never have the intention of putting the password in url** because others can see it there.

Comment: I see, I actually didn't want the password to auto fill. I just put that in for an example. I do not have access to change the html. I was just thinking that maybe there was a way.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a way in your case.

Comment: @user3671228 If an answer works for you, you should mark it as accepted for others to know that it worked.